# apache access.log.3 and access.log.4 are identical, is this normal?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

Ive been running access.log files through awk and sort uniq to get number of page hits but when i ran it today the count was lower then yesterday, after checking the logs, logs 3, 4 5 and 7 are identical. Does this mean someone copied the logs or is this normal behavior for apache?

Answer (score 0):

That is not normal. Each log line contains a time stamp, so the only reasonable way the different log files could be identical would be if they were completely empty. And web servers rarely have so little traffic that any of those files would be empty.

It is not Apache which creates all of those files. Apache only writes to the one name you have configured. And there will usually be a `logrotate` cron job which renames the file and signals Apache to create a new log file.

The first two guesses that come to my mind for why those files could end up being identical would be:

- Something got messed up in how `logrotate` was being used - possibly involving multiple concurrent invocations of `logrotate` attempting to rotate the files simultaneously. However I can't come up with an exact set of circumstances which would produce what you saw.
- Somebody was trying to extract some data from these log files and accidentally made a typo causing a command to write to one of the log files instead of reading. The possibility of making such mistakes is one of the reasons you shouldn't run such commands as a user with write access to the log files in the first place.